# Area of a triangle ABC

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Triangle's $ABC$ angle $C=60°$, $AB = AC+2 = BC-1$.

Find the area of this triangle.

I've tried writing $AB$ as $x$ so $AC= x-2$ and $BC = x+1$.

Then i calculated the area with

$$\frac12\sin(60°)\cdot(x-2)\cdot(x+1)=\frac12\sin(60°)\cdot(x^2-x-2)$$

Now i have no idea what to do next.

Comment: If $AB=x$ then $AC=x-2$, $BC=x+1$

Comment: Well, *immediately* next is replace $\sin 60 $ with $\frac {\sqrt 3}2$.... then after that...;)   Well, then after that, solve for $x$ with either/or law of sines or cosigns.

Comment: Law of cosines gives us $AB^2 = AC^2 + BC^2 - 2AC*BC\cos 60$ and as $\cos 60 =\frac 12$ this is a quadratic equation that will give us $x$.

Answer (score 3):

If $AB=x$, then $AC=x-2,BC=x+1$.

Now use the cosine formula: $$x^2=(x-2)^2+(x+1)^2-(x-2)(x+1)$$ Expanding we get $x=7$. So the longest side is 8 and the height $AC\sin60^o=5\sqrt3/2$. Hence the area is $10\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AC=x$ then $AB=x+2$ and $BC=x+3$.

To find $x$ we can use

- $AB^2=AC^2+BC^2-2\cdot AC\cdot BC \cos (60°)$ ([**law of cosine**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines))

Finally we can evaluate the area with the formula you have already mentioned.

Comment: You should probably proofread this for errors.

Comment: @TedShifrin Opsss...thanks I fix!

Comment: What is $A$ in your first equation?

Comment: It certainly wasn't clear to me when $A$ is appearing six or seven other times as a vertex.

Comment: @gimusi: $BC=x+3$, no?

Comment: @TedShifrin I've put that in the wrong position!

Comment: @Vasya I can't do that excercise! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the theorem of cosines we get
$$c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$$
substituting $$c=b+2,a=b+3$$ we get an equation for $b$:
$$(b+2)^2=(b+3)^2+b^2-2(b+3)b\cos(\frac{\pi}{3})$$